# Simple question, set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory, soft-question, notation

I'm having quite a bit if trouble finding a straight answer on how one should properly denote the set of all even and all naturals respectively. What is the standard, universally understood way to signify these?

Comment: The term *natural number* is ambiguous, unfortunately. For many of us, including me, it means *non-negative integer*, and the set of natural numbers is denoted by $\Bbb N$ or by $\omega$. For some it means *positive integer*, and some of those people use $\Bbb N$ to denote *their* notion of natural number, thereby making the notation ambiguous.

Answer (score 1):

Natural Numbers are denoted $\mathbb{N}$.

Even Numbers are denoted $2\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Okay, so natural numbers are represented as $\mathbb{N}$ and even numbers are represented as $2\mathbb{N}$. But how can we prove the denotation of the even numbers set?

Comment: @ObinnaNwakwue What do you mean prove? Even numbers are of the form $2n$, so they are $2\mathbb{N}$ by definition.

Comment: "But how can we prove the denotation of the even numbers set?"  I do not know what this question means. Notation is convention. I can denote the set of even numbers as PinKhP34do$\omega$foo8P but nobody would understand what I meant it I did. In context most people would assume $A + B$ to mean $\{a+b|a \in A; b \in B\}$ and with almost no coaxing assume $2A$ to mean $\{2b|b \in A\}$.  It's not a matter of *proving* anything.  It's a matter of saying "Let $a\in PinKhP34do\omega foo8P$. Do you know what I mean by that".  "Um... no." "Okay, Let $a \in 2\mathbb N$. Better?". "a is even?" "exactly"

Comment: Although, I'm not one hundred percent sure how universally $2\mathbb N$ is accepted.  There's nothing wrong with simply stating: "For this paper I am going to denote the set of even numbers as $2\mathbb N$." or  "For this paper I am going to denote the set of even numbers as $\mathbb E$." Or " "For this paper I am going to denote the set of even numbers as $\mathbb {PinKhP34do\omega foo8P}$."

Comment: I meant...wait, never mind, I might have a generalization of this.

Answer (score 1):

Usually if $n\in \mathbb N$ ,    $\space n\mathbb N=\{\alpha\equiv 0\space mod (n) |\alpha \in \mathbb N\}$. So $2\mathbb N$ is the set of all even numbers.(Positive obviously).

Comment: Che serate impegnative eh? (entrambi, anzi, tutti e tre)

Comment: @GiuseppeBargagnati Pappalettera

Comment: I made a mistake in asking my question. It was supposed to ask the notation regarding even and odd naturals. 2N seems fair for evens...I was using N sub o and N sub e...is that workable?